# what is the difference between "&" and "and" in Python?

Tags: python, operator-keyword

The first code gives `True` but the second gives an error saying

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'

What is the difference between `&` and `and` operator in Python? Isn't it the same?

```
student = "Justin"
```

first code

```
print(student == "Justin" and 1 == 1)
```

second code

```
print(student == "Justin" & 1 == 1)
```

Comment: `and` is a boolean and, `&` is a bitwise and, and it had a higher precedence

Comment: A good explanation https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-and-and-in-python/

Answer (score 11):

`&` is the bit-AND operator.

```
1 & 1 = 1
3 & 2 = 2
2 & 1 = 0
```

while `and` is the boolean operator.

You can use `&` for boolean expression and get correct answer since `True` is equivalent to 1 and `False` is 0, `1 & 0 = 0`. 0 is equivalent to False and Python did a type casting to Boolean. That's why you get boolean result when using `&` for booleans

Comment: In python, you can also customize the operator for a class. For example, adding `def __and__(...)` to `Foo` class, you can use `Foo() & something`

Comment: there is no type casting...