# Python if statement not working correctly and no idea why

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement, boolean

In my code I iterate through dataframes of each year to calculate the number of wins (increase between numbers) and losses (decrease between numbers), and the ratio of wins to losses. The loop I run correctly displays the right number of wins and losses in the dataframe they are eventually pushed to. However, when calculating the win/loss ratio, the if statement isn't working for no real reason. Here is the loop:

```
trades = []
wins = []
losses = []
winloss = []
for df in df_years_grouped:
        total_trades = len(df)
        trades.append(total_trades)
        
        win = 0
        loss = 0
        for i, row in df.iterrows():
            if i == 0:
                continue
            elif (df[1][i] > df[1][i-1]):
                win += 1
            elif (df[1][i] < df[1][i-1]):
                loss += 1
        wins.append(win)
        losses.append(loss)
        
        if win == 0 & loss == 0:
            winloss.append(0)
        elif win > 0 & loss == 0:
            winloss.append('All Wins')
        elif win == 0 & loss > 0:
            winloss.append('All Losses')
        else:
            winloss.append(win/loss)
```

Here is the outcome in the Dataframe:

```
Trades Win  Lose W/L 
11     5    5    All Wins
42     21   20   All Wins
35     16   18   All Wins
14     9    4    All Wins
23     13   9    All Wins
12     7    4    All Wins
4      2    1    All Wins
4      2    1    All Wins
11     5    5    All Wins
6      3    2    All Wins
0      0    0    0
9      6    2    All Wins
2      0    1    0
16     6    9    All Wins
3      0    2    0
14     7    6    All Wins
206   106   99   1.070707
```

As you can see it works on one or two but fails on the most, making most of them wins?

Comment: I think you meant: `if win == 0 and loss == 0:` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should be using "and" instead of "&" in the if statements. You can read up on the differences here:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-and-and-in-python/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is between 'and' and '&'

Give the following a read:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-and-and-in-python/

'and' is the Locigal AND whereas '&' is the bit-and 'AND'

```
a = 14
b = 4
  
print(b and a) - 14
print(b & a) - 4
```

See here too:
[what is the difference between "&" and "and" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67645225/what-is-the-difference-between-and-and-in-python)

I would suggest changing you code to use the logical AND

or maybe the following if you do not mind more IF statements

```
if win == 0:
    if loss == 0
        winloss.append(0)
    elif loss > 0:
        winloss.append('All Losses')
elif win > 0:
    if loss == 0:
        winloss.append('All Wins')   
else:
    winloss.append(win/loss)
```

I personally would also find this easier to read as an external user

Answer (score 0):

You should use `and` instead of `&`, their have different priority:
`win == 0 & loss == 0` is equivalent to `win == (0 & loss) == 0`:

```py
import ast
assert ast.dump(ast.parse("win == 0 & loss == 0")) == ast.dump(ast.parse("win == (0 & loss) == 0"))
```