# Is n power of three - Python

Tags: python, recursion

Leet-Code 326. Power of Three: Question Link: https://leetcode.com/problems/power-of-three/description/

My Code:

```
 class Solution:
    def isPowerOfThree(self, n: int) -> bool:
        print(n)
        if n % 3 == 0:
            if n == 3:
                return True 
            return self.isPowerOfThree(n/3)
        else: return False
```

I a getting the following error. Any help!
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object

Comment: I would re-organize the code a bit with having your quick returns (`n<=0`, `n==3` and `n%3 !=0`) immediately after your `print` statement. Also, you might avoid a recursive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function has no way of handling 0. If you step through the function, you print "0" (which is why it's the first thing that fails after exceeding the recursion depth), then it evaluates `0 % 3 == 0`. That's `True`, so it goes further. `0 == 3` is `False`, so it returns `self.isPowerOfThree(0)`, and you're back where you started (infinite recursion).

Hope this helped.

Comment: return (n >= 0) & ((math.log10(n)/ math.log10(3) % 1) == 0)  This should have worked too, but it got a math error. Any idea? @SebastianNeumann

Comment: Don't forget to check for negative numbers. Also `0` is not a power of three

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67645225/what-is-the-difference-between-and-and-in-python - `&` is "bitwise and" without short-circuiting, so `math.log10(n)` is being evaluated even if n<0