# Python bitwise operation on condtion statement 'unexpected' behavior

Tags: python

I'm new to python programing. While solving a practice problem and experimenting with bitwise operation, I ran into unexpected output:

```py
index = 0
time = '?'

print(index)
print(index == 1)
print(time[0].isnumeric())
print(index == 1 & time[0].isnumeric())
print(index == 1 and time[0].isnumeric())
```

**Output:**

```
0
False
False
True
False
```

As far as I understand:

- `False and False` should result in `False` : Boolean operation
- `False & False` should result in `False` : Bitwise operation

Based on the above understanding when I performed bitwise operation on condition statement I getting the output as 'True'. When I change to boolean operation, I get the expected output of 'False'.

Can someone please explain this behavior, I'm sure that I'm missing something.
Thanks.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Reopened because the supposed duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67645225/what-is-the-difference-between-and-and-in-python didn't help in any way except for one mention of the word 'precedence' in a comment with no explanation which a beginner wouldn't understand/notice. And the 'duplicate' which *that* links to is not helpful for either of those questions, at least not on the surface.

Comment: I've edited the code to only include what's relevant, please take note as an example of a good [mcve].

Comment: Thank you @AlexHall, yup going ahead will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitwise operations have similar precedence to other mathematical operations. Just as you would want `1 + 2 == 3` to be interpreted as `(1 + 2) == 3` rather than `1 + (2 == 3)`,

```
index == 1 & time[0].isnumeric()
```

is interpreted as

```
index == (1 & time[0].isnumeric())
```

i.e.

```
0 == (1 & False)
```

In Python, `False == 0` and `1 == True`, so `1 & False == 1 & 0 == 0`.

On the other hand,

```
index == 1 and time[0].isnumeric()
```

is interpreted as

```
(index == 1) and time[0].isnumeric()
```

just as you would want `a == b and c == d` to be interpreted as `(a == b) and (c == d)` rather than `a == (b and c) == d`.

Comment: Thank you @Alex for explaining it in such a easy way.
Even though I learned in tutorial, bitwise operations have similar precedence to mathematical operations, I missed to put two and two together. My bad. Thank you for your help. :D